# Xamarin, why can't my if/else statement, retrieving data from Settings.plugin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

`LastPickName` is not empty but it kept picking the else statement... maybe I'm putting it in the wrong area?

I have a label text to output what's in `LastPickName` just to make sure it's not empty or empty.

```cs
using Plugin.Settings;
using Plugin.Settings.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App424
{
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        private static ISettings AppSettings =>  CrossSettings.Current;

        public static string LastPickValue
        {
            get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(LastPickValue), string.Empty);
            set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(LastPickValue), value);
        }

        public static string LastPickName
        {
            get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(LastPickName), string.Empty);
            set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(LastPickName), value);
        }
        public object LastPickname { get; private set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Right1");
            list.Add("Right2");
            list.Add("Right3");
            list.Add("Right4");

            //populate picker selection
            drainlocationPicker1.ItemsSource = list;

            //Set the default value
            drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem = LastPickValue;
            nameEntry.Placeholder = LastPickName;
            //names.Text = LastPickName;
            nameLabel.Text = LastPickName;

            if (LastPickName == null)
            {
                settingsButton.IsVisible = true;
                nextButton.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                nextButton.IsVisible = true;
                settingsButton.IsVisible = false;
            }

            void Handle_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
            {
                LastPickName = nameEntry.Text;
            }

            private void DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string nlocation1 = (string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem;
                LastPickValue = nlocation1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LastPickName` is empty it should show `settingsButton` if not show `nextButton`.
`LastPickName` is empty why is it not showing `settingsButton`?

Comment: What do you mean by “empty” here? Is it null or not, since that’s what you’re checking. Not some definition of “empty.”

Comment: null is empty right?  empty like there's no value there. no data has been save.

Comment: Null is null. “Empty” can be an empty string, for example. What does your debugger tell you when you put a breakpoint there and check the value?

Comment: Ok now i get it. I am looking for empty string.  What is null? Null is invalid data?

Comment: @hypnocool:

check like this,

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastPickName))

Comment: @KrunalBagadia : So this works if (LastPickName == "") and yours  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastPickName))  but I see more tutorial using your syntax.  What is the advantage of using NullorEmpty than just comparing to empty string?

Answer (score 0):

if (LastPickName == "")
i thought null is empty but as Sami commented it's not.